# How to generate random password with the fixed length in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Is there a quick way to generate random password with fixed length? (for example, 8 digits, letter/number/underscore)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
user> (defn fixed-length-password
        ([] (fixed-length-password 8))
        ([n]
           (let [chars (map char (range 33 127))
                 password (take n (repeatedly #(rand-nth chars)))]
             (reduce str password))))      
#'user/fixed-length-password
user> (fixed-length-password 10)
;=> "N&L[yyLUI4"
user> (fixed-length-password 10)
;-> "8JSF-:?si."
user> (fixed-length-password 10)
;=> "EbKS~?*J*h"
```

Comment: Problem with **\ (backslash)**: Whenever there's a backslash in the string, it appears **twice**. Maybe this is due to the inner data structure of Clojure. How to avoid it?

Comment: @Nick Try the following 

    (defn fixed-length-password
      ([] (fixed-length-password 8))
      ([n]
         (let [chars (map char (range 33 127))
               password (take n (repeatedly #(rand-nth chars)))
               pass-str (reduce str password)]
           (clojure.string/replace pass-str "\\" "/"))))

Comment: That's cool. Can you explain how does `(replace pass-str "\\" "/")` work? Why replace double backslash with one forwardslash? Thank you!

Comment: @Nick The \ char is a prefix for escaping characters within a String. For example, if you were to evaluate "\a", you would get a `RuntimeException` for an "Unsupported escape character". No such error would occur if you take "\a" and make it "\\a".


    (clojure.string/replace "string\\" 
                            "\\" 
                            "/")


Outside of strings, at least with Clojure, a single slash prefixing a character represents the character itself.

    user> (= \a (first "abc"))
    ;=> true

Comment: I think I understand most of your explanation on escaping a char; but why did **/ (forward-slash)** come in? Replace \\ with /, thus left no \ at all?

Comment: You don't have to replace that character but you have to make sure that it's escaped for strings. In the given example, that character is replaced because that character is considered an escaped character in dbs, file formats, etc...

Comment: I still could not understand why `(replace pass-str "\\" "/")`. I'm new to Clojure, and not smart enough:(

Comment: @Nick did you see my last comment explaining the replacement?

Comment: Thank you for your patient. Yes, I've read it. My understanding is: in order to fix the double backslash \\ bug in the result, you use `(replace pass-str "\\" "/")`, that is, replace \\ with \, right? If so, how can the result string contain \ ? Does that mean the opportunity for / to appear in the result string is great than \?

Comment: @Nick Not exactly. The backslash doesn't have to be replaced. I replaced the backslash with the forward slash because your original comment stated that you didn't like the escaped slash => ` \\ ` . An escaped slash is the same as any other escaped character => ` \a \b \c \\ `

Comment: Ah! So it is! Take this as an example: I want 8 chars for password. But the program gives me 9:  Kx%;g\"t8 I noticed that the " is escaped. There's nothing to blame your program-it's logically right; however, due to the char representation in Clojure, I got more chars than I want, is there a way to solve this, except replace the special characters?

Comment: @Nick You can try (dec n). For example, if you supply 8 to the fn, 7 is actually the take value.

If this works for you, would you mind marking the answer?

Comment: I asked for 8 chars, most of the time, the program returns 8 chars, but sometimes it returns 9 chars. I can't count each time manually.

Comment: I run the program twice: The first run it returns 8 chars. The second run, it return 10 chars. `user> (fixed-length-password)
"U7g~|$#R"
user> (fixed-length-password)
"F\":n\\wsW"`

Comment: @Nick That's not actually 10 chars. There's an escaped double-quote and an escaped backslash.

`user> (count "F\":n\\wsW")
;=> 8`

Comment: @Nick Print the password with the escaped chars and you'll see => `user> (println "F\":n\\wsW") ;=> F":n\wsW`

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you for your kindly help and your great patient. Cloujure community is really great! I was so fooled by this problem -- there're still a lot to learn for me. I wish you happy!

Comment: No problem. Check out the Clojure cheat sheet and look for character literal => http://clojure.org/cheatsheet

Comment: using `apply` instead of `reduce` will be faster (specially on longer strings). Also much faster if you don't calculate `chars` on every run and just bind it to a global value (outside of the function) so it's only calculated once, on compile time.

Answer (score 5):

```
user> (defn fixed-length-password
        ([] (fixed-length-password 8))
        ([n]
           (let [chars-between #(map char (range (int %1) (inc (int %2))))
                 chars (concat (chars-between \0 \9)
                               (chars-between \a \z)
                               (chars-between \A \Z)
                               [\_])
                 password (take n (repeatedly #(rand-nth chars)))]
             (reduce str password))))      
#'user/fixed-length-password
user> (fixed-length-password 10)
;=> "Pfm0hwppMr"
user> (fixed-length-password 10)
;-> "n6lQoz_KGd"
user> (fixed-length-password 10)
;=> "vCkubQR75Z"
```

This is a slight change on runexec's answer, where you can see how to select what characters your random string should be using.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use the `crypto-random`library. It is by the same author of `Compojure`, and suited for cryptographic purposes.

Notice that it wraps Java libraries under the hood (`java.security`and `apache-commons`. Have a look at the code ! It's so tiny.

Specifically in your case you may be looking for the `hex`function, so the solution would be : `(crypto.random/hex size)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
(defn rand-string [characters n]
  (->> (fn [] (rand-nth characters))
       repeatedly
       (take n)
       (apply str)))
```

It's not deterministic as-is because rand-nth has side-effects, but it should be enough for you to get started with.

Comment: Perhaps `(defn rand-string [chars n] (->> #(rand-nth (vec chars)) (repeatedly n) (apply str)))`. The `vec` makes sure that the look-up is fast.